# Finding a Line starting with Specific String and Replace it with a New Line

Tags: groovy

In my file `AppMacros.h`, I have a line `#define TARGET_DEVICE XXX`. `XXX` will change later, so I want to find what lines start with `#define TARGET_DEVICE` string and replace it with specific string such as `#define TARGET_DEVICE YYY`.

Anyone know how to make it in Groovy?

Comment: no luck with mine or Opal answer? Different approaches (regex, contains) but both works

Comment: Sorry for late reply, there's a problem with my macbook. I have no luck with both of yours and I ended up using this way. I write a python script and run it successful. Anw thank so much for helping me.

Comment: no problem, glad to know you have solved. Have a good day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's just a sample - no idea if you need anything more advanced:

```
def txt = '''
#define TARGET_DEVICE XXX
lol
#define TARGET_DEVICE XXX
olo
#define TARGET_DEVICE XXX
'''

def replaced = txt.split('\n').collect { l ->
    def targetLine = l.toLowerCase().startsWith('#define target_device')
    targetLine ? '#define TARGET_DEVICE YYY' : l
}.join('\n')

println replaced
```

Answer (score 1):

I've assumed you pass the filename from the command line (this works as a `sed -i~` if you know it) and the code create an output file (same name but with a `~` as suffix):

```
def pattern    = /^\s*(#define\s+TARGET_DEVICE)\s+.*/
def ls         =  System.getProperty("line.separator")
def newDevice  =  "XXX"
File fin       =  new File(args[0]);
File fout      =  new File("${fin.name}~")

if( fin.exists() && !fin.isDirectory() )
{
  fin.eachLine { line ->
      line = line.replaceAll(pattern) {
        entireMatch, prefix ->
          "${prefix} ${newDevice}"
      }
      fout.append("${line}${ls}")
      //or println line
      //or linesAccumulator << line
  }
} else {
  println "File ${args[0]} not exists or is a directory"
  System.exit 5
}
```

**NB**: this works also on very large files cause process the file line by line. The regex used relaxes the space constraints (if a line has multiple spaces or tabs it matches the line anyway).